# Turn off logging for a package in Dropwizard app

Tags: java, logging, dropwizard

I need to disable logging for a specific package of a 3rd party library in my Dropwizard app. I've tried this in the Dropwizard configuration file:

```
logging:
    loggers:
       org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener: WARN
```

which is documented should work but I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported format of logger 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener'
```

Any help or thoughts greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The answer for me was to put "OFF" in quotes. Not sure why - I didn't find any documentation of this, I just tried it and it worked!

Comment: Had the same issue. The quotes are required but only for "OFF".

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer. Worked for me. I looked into the DW code, probably this line is the reason why you need double quotes: 
    if (jsonNode.isTextual()) {...happy } else {.... slowly walk down a path of throwing exception or doing something else}